# Search data through different columns using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fetch the data by using a search textfield. The issue is right now the code only works on a single column which has [1] index. I want to fetch the data from 3 columns using the same textfield.
Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="search_text"]').on('keyup', function() {

          var input, filter, tr, td, i;

          input  = $(this);
          filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
          tr     = $("table tr");

          for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
              td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
              if (td) {
                  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                      tr[i].style.display = "";
                  } else {
                      tr[i].style.display = "none";
                  }
              }
          }
      })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest expansion of what you already have could be:

```
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var line = "";
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) line += td.innerHTML.toUpperCase();

    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    if (td) line += td.innerHTML.toUpperCase();

    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[7];
    if (td) line += td.innerHTML.toUpperCase();

    if (line.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

If you stop mixing jquery and vanilla javascript, you'll get:

```
tr = $("table tr");
tr.each(function() { 
    // which ever columns are required
    $(this).toggle($("td:eq(1),td:eq(2),td:eq(6)", tr).text().toUpperCase().indexof(filter) > -1);
}
```

(or use .filter instead of .each for a single line)

Answer (score 0):

To make this work where it only selects a subset of the cells in the row you can use the `:nth-child()` selector. From there you can hide/show the parent `tr` based on any matches found.

Also note that the logic can be made a lot more simple by using jQuery's `filter()` method.

In the example below you can see that only the `An`, `Bn` and `Cn` fields are valid in the searchbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $rows = $('table tr');
  let $cells = $rows.find('td').filter(':nth-child(-n+3)');
  
  $('input[name="search_text"]').on('input', function() {
    $rows.hide();
    let searchValue = $(this).val().trim().toUpperCase();
    $cells.filter((i, el) => el.textContent.trim().toUpperCase().indexOf(searchValue) != -1).closest('tr').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search_text" />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C1</td>
      <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>C2</td>
      <td>D2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td>C3</td>
      <td>D3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```